# Emptying array when it matches another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I'm trying to match 2 different arrays. If the same cells match, I want to remove that cell from one array using the .slice method.

Edit: What I'm trying to do is remove a number from array1 if array2 contains a matching number. The way the code works now is that it only deletes 1 entry. I want all the entries deleted from the first array.

```
array1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 10];
array2 = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8];

var misc = function deleteValues(array, arayy) {
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if ( arayy[i] == array[i]) {
      array.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return array;
};
```

I try to run this and under console log, the array1 is unchanged. It seems like the splice method isn't removing any cells. I searched SE, but couldn't find anything that could help me.

Comment: How did you actually run `misc()`?

Comment: What is expected result of `array1` after call to `misc` ?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger, or would you simply rather someone else doing that?

Comment: The expected result is to only have 10 remaining in array1, removing all similarities it has to array2.

Comment: Technically the item at 7 is matched in the other array by 6, so the resulting array should have `[7,10]`.

Comment: Are you simply trying to remove a number if the other array contains that number? That is a little different..

Comment: @TravisJ It's possible that is what the user might mean, using terminology such as "cells" makes it seem position based.

Comment: Travis...yes, exactly. That's what I'm trying to do. Sorry for being unclear. JS newbie checking in.

Comment: @user2989913 Could you edit your question to make that more clear? As you are not really looking for *matching* arrays.

Comment: The main reason why your code doesn't work is because you have a typo - `if ( arayy == array[i]) {` should be `if ( arayy[i] == array[i]) {`. This is still incorrect, however, so see Travis J's answer for a real solution.

Comment: Giving a name to a function expression is pointless (other than for debugging) if the name isn't used in the function itself.

Answer (score 3):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/9ese4yw4/)***

The problem is that you are modifying one of the arrays as you iterate, but you are still using the same index. The end result is that you end up comparing the wrong indexes to each other after the first removal. Use two indexes, have one offset back down when it removes an item, and have the other simply iterate.

```
var misc = function deleteValues(array, arayy) {
    for(var i = 0, j = 0; i < array.length; i++, j++) {
        if ( arayy[j] == array[i]) {
            array.splice(i--, 1);
        }
    }
    return array;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Works pretty well. One question: What's the logic behind using "i--" here?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Works pretty well. One question: What's the logic behind using "i--" here? That has me confused because wouldn't i-- equal to -1, since we started with an index of 0?

Comment: is this what you want, because this does what you seem to be asking, filters down to 7 and 10, by checking the indexes match, but elsewhere you imply you want to filter out all values in array2 from array1 leaving only 10

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to remove items from the first array if the values are also in the second. The *reduceRight* method seems suitable as it iterates from right to left over the array, hence removing items doesn't affect the index of subsequent elements in the array. The same result can be achieved with a decrementing loop.

Also, I think function declarations are better than assignment of expressions, but each to their own.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 10];
var array2 = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8];

function deleteValues(arr0, arr1) {
  arr0.reduceRight(function(x, value, index) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(value) != -1) {
      arr0.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },'');

  // Not necessary but handy for chaining
  return arr0;
}

document.write(deleteValues(array1, array2));
```

Using an arrow function, the above can be reduced to:

```
function deleteValues(arr0, arr1) {
  arr0.reduceRight((x, v, i) => arr1.indexOf(v) != -1? arr0.splice(i, 1):'');
  return arr0;
}
```